# Comparing header values in 2 Google Sheets docs and pasting the entire column if they match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I can't seem to get this script to work. I have a template that I use for billing purposes and I'm trying to clone that sheet, then update the information for new customers, contracts etc at the end of every month. I don't want all the information from the "bsf" spreadsheet, but only columns that were used in my billing template. I tested it and everything works up to, but not including, the for loop. Something in there is going haywire.

With the for loop, I'm trying to cycle through each column, grab it, compare the header from my template doc to the BSF doc, and if they match, paste the entire column into my new billing document. If not, I want it to move on to the next column and do the exact same thing.

```
function newBillingDoc() {
  var billingTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B1U5evaRId6xYi1rNGhZbUtBV0U");
  var newId = DriveApp.getFileById(billingTemplate.getId()).makeCopy("billing doc template", destFolder).getId();
  var billingMaster = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newId).getSheetByName('2016 Master');
  billingMaster.clearContents();

  var bsf = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qKaZXpCk7Vw3uvRNft8Cl4vuCC_6PMRR9xyc2tNE7Cc').getSheetByName('Copy of 2016 Master');
  var lastRow = bsf.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = bsf.getLastColumn();
  var billingHeader = billingTemplate.getSheetByName('2016 Master').getRange('A1:J1').getValue();
  billingMaster.getRange('A1:J1').setValue(billingHeader);

for(var j = 1; j < lastColumn; j++); {
    var billingBody = billingMaster.getRange(1, j, lastRow, 1);
    billingHeader = billingTemplate.getSheetByName('2016 Master').getRange(1, j, 1, 1).getValue();
    var masterHeader  = bsf.getRange(1, j, 1, 1).getValue();
    if (billingHeader == masterHeader) {
      var billingBodyChunk = bsf.getRange(1, j, lastRow, 1).getValues();
      billingBody.setValues(billingBodyChunk);
    }
  }
}
```

When I put `billing Header` and `masterHeader` into `Logger.log(data)` I get the following:

```
[16-05-31 16:01:15:403 PDT] [[]]
[16-05-31 16:01:15:403 PDT] [[Percentage]]
```

I think that I need to declare an array or something, but I really don't know. I tried adding arrays but it didn't seem to work well with the objects I'm working with.

Comment: Change both instances of `.getValues()` to `.getValue()`. Also (perhaps an answer to a question you didn't ask), much better to get all the data first with say `.getDataRange().getValues()`, and iterate through the resultant 2D arrays.

Comment: I've tried this, as well as writing the billingHeader in before the for loop (as suggested by Bobby S), but it isn't working. You just mean the two `getValues()` after the variable declarations for masterHeader and billingHeader, correct?

I will update the initial question with my updated code. I'll keep your comment re: `getDataRange().getValues()` in mind! This is really my first attempt at coding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing the headers from master to billing, however the headers from master will never be copied over billing and thus within your for loop the if statement will never resolve to true.  Try copying over your row 1 headers first.  That should allow the if statement nice fire.

Comment: I've tried this and it still isn't working. The top row is successfully carrying over, but nothing else is filling in.